# incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to launch rails server I get the following output, and the server doesn't open. New to both ruby and rails.

/Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb:13:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle (fatal)
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb:13:in`'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in`'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json.rb:58:in `require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json.rb:58:in`'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:2:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:12:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails.rb:11:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:73:in`server'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
    from /Users/Seth/railsbridge/test_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/Seth/railsbridge/test_app/bin/rails:9:in`'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`call'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`load'
    from /Users/Seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Seth/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:13:in`require'
    from /Users/Seth/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in`load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `'

Comment: You might want to try uninstalling and reinstalling that gem, or that version of Ruby with `rvm`.

Comment: If the problem persist, just use [railsinstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en)

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to link a different lib than the one when it was build.
Did you copy the build from other location or updated you libs?
Anyway a reinstall should work since it will build it again.